# How to work on 2 MySQL databases at the same time using PHPMyAdmin through Plesk?

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, database

I am trying to open 2 instances of PHPMyAdmin by clicking on the "manage database" link in Plesk. But the challenge is I seem to be only allowed to work on 1 database at a time as when I try and open another the original tab refreshes losing me access to the originally open DB and giving me access to the new one I just click on only.

How do I open both please?

Just to reiterate I am using Plesk on Windows Server Edition 2008 R2. The DB software is PHPMyAdmin and the databases are MySQL.

I have tried right clicking and that did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is saving what db you are using in your cookies.  Use two different browsers.  Or use incognito/private browsing for one session so it has a separate set of cookies.

Comment: This seems like it should work but I found my own solution. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way to access the databases. I must of been using a client button rather than an admin one.

Visit this page where SERVER is your server IP address and port.

SERVER://server/db_server_databases.php?db_server_id=1

Or follow the breadcrumbs "Home>Tools & Settings>Database Servers"

Then click on "Webadmin". This will open all databases you are allowed access to as admin.